# customheaders in web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, access-control, custom-headers, http-protocols

How can i add entities/parameters into my asp.net mvc application. I want to allow cors to send ajax-requests into a database via asp.net webservice. Does anyone have experience fixing this?

```
<httpProtocol>  
<customHeaders>  
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type" />  
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=test.qvw&lang=en-US&host=QVS%40servb"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />  
 </customHeaders>
```

It shows me an error underlining the lang and the host section of the value, where i want to access.

Warm regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are adding them in correct section. Change the whole url to just localhost and it will work

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type" />  
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />  
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is in the same section as you mentioned. It is underlining the lang and host. The Error is Entity 'lang'/'host' is not defined.

Comment: did not notice that. @AzOez. you just need to mention localhost. full Url is not needed

Comment: @AzOez Did this help you ?

Comment: No but i am getting an new error which says: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:1052/SaveComment' opendoc.htm?document...=QVS%40serv:1 from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://127.0.0.1' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Comment: After that error, i changed the config file to http://localhost again and i am getting an error which says: Access to XMLHttpRequest at  'http://localhost:1052/SaveComment' opendoc.htm?document...=QVS%40serv23:1 from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass acess control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: @AzOez There is another way by which we can set all of them as "*". though it is not recommended, you can try to put * in all and check if it works for you. After that you can find out if there is really a problem with the configuration or not